# Showing that $ \int_{10}^\infty \frac{e^x}{x^{1 + \frac{1}{x}} (e^x -1)}dx$ diverge

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Is it true that $  \displaystyle \int_{10}^\infty  \cfrac{e^x}{x^{1 + \frac{1}{x}} (e^x -1)}dx$ diverge since $  \displaystyle \int_{10}^\infty  \cfrac{e^x}{x^{1 + \frac{1}{x}} (e^x -1)}dx >   \displaystyle \int_{10}^\infty  \cfrac{e^x}{x^{1 + \frac{1}{x}}e^x }dx=\displaystyle \int_{10}^\infty  \cfrac{1}{x^{1 + \frac{1}{x}} }dx$  and $\displaystyle \int_{10}^\infty  \cfrac{1}{x^{1 + \frac{1}{x}} }dx$ diverges by $p$-test?

Comment: I seek for an alternative proof so I am asking something different.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\Bigl((1+\frac{1}{x})\ln (x)-\ln (x)\Bigr)=0$$
then
$$ x^{1+\frac{1}{x}} \sim x \; (x\to +\infty) $$

on the other hand
$$e^x\sim (e^x-1)  \; (x \to +\infty) $$

thus

$$f (x)\sim \frac {1}{x} \;(x\to+\infty) $$

so
$$\int^{+\infty}f (x)dx \text { diverges} $$